# How to create github webhook on repo deletion

Tags: git, github, pygithub

I have created [Oauth App](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/creating-an-oauth-app) to get user token and i'm using [PyGithub](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html) to create repos and add hooks/events to them. I'm trying to figure out if a repo the Oauthapp created is deleted using a webhook.

The available hooks list includes tracking of creating pull/push requests etc.. but it doesn't include events for repo deletion tracking .

Is this even available in Github Restapi or we just can't tell if a repo created by Oauth app still exist or not automatically without setting scheduler to check every x mins.

Comment: The GitHub web hooks are mostly for events that occur inside a repository. Deleting the repository entirely doesn't happen *in* a repository, but rather *outside* a repository. Whether there's some way to detect it, I don't know; that's a GitHub question.

Answer (score 0):

This is available but not for OAuth
https://docs.github.com/en/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads?actionType=deleted#repository